# Finding $T^{\perp}$!

Tags: hilbert-spaces, inner-products, orthogonality

Let $\mathbb{K}=\mathbb{R}$, and let's consider, in $l^{2}$, the set $T=\left\{(\lambda_{n})_{n}\in l^{2}: \displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{\lambda_{n}}{\sqrt{n}}=0\right\}$; I am asked to find $T^{\perp}$:

Here is my attempt: I am going to try to show that $T^{\perp}=\{\mathbf{0}\}$; for showing this, I am going to take $x=(\lambda_{n})_{n}\in T^{\perp}$, and try to show that $\lambda_{n}=0$, $\forall n\in\mathbb{N}$.

So, let, $x=(\lambda_{n})_{n}\in T^{\perp}$, then, by definition of $T^{\perp}$, $\forall y\in T$, $\langle x,y \rangle = 0$.
I have seen that for example, $y_{1}=(1,-\sqrt{2},0,...,0,...)=e_{1}-\sqrt{2} \cdot e_{2}$ is an element of $T$, so taking on account what I have said, $\langle x,y_{1}\rangle =\lambda_{1}-\sqrt{2}\cdot \lambda_{2}=0$, and so $\lambda_{1}=\sqrt{2}\cdot \lambda_{2}$. Similiarly, is easy to show that $y_{n}=e_{1}-\sqrt{n}\cdot e_{n}$ is actually an element of $T$, so, we can deduce that $\lambda_{1}=\sqrt{n}\cdot \lambda_{n}$, $\forall n\in \mathbb{N}$... Nevertheless, I am not able to continue (in order to prove that $\lambda_{n}=0, \forall n\in \mathbb{N}$)... Someone could give me a hint/some help?

Thanks in advanced!

Comment: You recieved 2 answers to your question. Is any of them what you needed? If so, consider *accepting* the best answer and upvoting all useful answers you got. That's how the site works.

Comment: @5xum Yes, sorry! I didn't remember to do it! Sorry for the long wait!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $\lambda_1\ne0$, then $\lambda_n=\frac{\lambda_1}{\sqrt n}$. But $\left(\frac{\lambda_1}{\sqrt n}\right)_{n\in\Bbb N}=\lambda_1\left(\frac1{\sqrt n}\right)_{n\in\Bbb N}\notin\ell^2$. So, $T^\perp=\{0\}$.

Comment: Ok, I see! And, $\displaystyle \left(\frac{\lambda_{1}}{\sqrt{n}}\right)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ would not be in $l^{2}$ as $\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\left(\frac{\lambda_{1}}{\sqrt{n}} \right)^2=$ $=\lambda_{1}^{2} \cdot \displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\displaystyle\frac{1}{n}=\infty$, no? Thanks for answering!

Answer (score 2):

You have proven that $\lambda_n = \frac{\lambda_1}{\sqrt{n}}$.

Now, use the fact that $x\in\ell^2$, which means that $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty |\lambda_n|^2$$ must converge.